# Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/TableContainer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, npm-install

I want to import table container for my react application. but I can't use it because of my material ui version error. 
How i update my version to latest version. I suppose that it's the solution for that error. 
I have already tried npm uninstall and npm uninstall, but didn't solve yet. Help me.

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-react",
  "version": "1.6.0",
  "description": "Material Dashboard React. Coded by Creative Tim",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@khanacademy/react-multi-select": "^0.3.3",
    "@lls/react-light-calendar": "^2.0.7",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "^3.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-react-intl": "^3.4.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "material-ui-next-responsive-table": "^0.5.1",
    "multi-select-react": "^0.1.8",
    "multiselect-dropdown-react": "^1.0.5",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^1.2.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "prettier": "1.16.4",
    "prop-types": "15.7.1",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "react-bootstrap-dialog": "^0.13.0",
    "react-bootstrap-modal": "^4.2.0",
    "react-chartist": "0.13.3",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.4.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
    "react-devtools": "^4.4.0",
    "react-dialog": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dom": "16.8.1",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.6.4",
    "react-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dropdown-tree-select": "^2.1.1",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-light-calendar": "^1.0.3",
    "react-multiple-select-dropdown": "^2.0.0",
    "react-multiselect-checkboxes": "^0.1.1",
    "react-notification-alert": "0.0.12",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-notifications-component": "^2.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.1",
    "react-table-container": "^2.0.3",
    "react-toastify": "^5.4.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Go to `package.json` file in your project root.

2) Locate `@material-ui/core` in `dependencies`. Currently, you will see it as `"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.4"`.

3) Now edit the version number. For example, `"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.2"`.

4) Run `npm install`.

That's it!

You can follow this procedure for any dependency when you want to change the version. But make sure that those versions are compatible with each other dependencies (if any).

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

`@material-ui/core` version ^3.9.4 doesn't have `<TableContainer>`

so you need to update @materia-ui/core version

latest version v4.9.2, so please update version and try